# How to hide ports from linked containers in docker

Tags: docker-compose

I have a proxy nginx container that expose 80 and 443 ports, also I have several inner containers with services that expose another ports.

Unfortunately, this configuration expose all inner services (they are visible outside of docker)

How can I hide all services except proxy?

docker-compose example the next:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - front
      - cms
      - mongo
  front:
    container_name: front
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: front/
    ports:
      - '5001:80'
  cms:
    container_name: corp-cms
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: cms-backend
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't publish ports of the services to the host.

Use service names for service intercommunication.

You can use service names because

> [Docker Compose creates a default network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

as @David Maze noticed

Consider using [docker stacks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/).

Deploying you stack would be as simple as `docker stack deploy --compose-file [compose_file_path]`

Comment: [Docker Compose creates a `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you can use service names as host names to communicate between containers without any special setup.